# Looping over data to display on a table

Tags: angular

I have some JSON data I get back an API that I developed using express, I want to loop over the data and showcase it in a table but some elements are skipped and I have an idea why but I have no idea how to fix it other than using two loops, but I can not use *ngFor two times

Here is the JSON data :

```
 [
  [
    {
      SESSION_ID: "200",
      TERMINAL_ID: "Y6152114",
    },
    {
      SESSION_ID: "296",
      TERMINAL_ID: "Y615224",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      TERMINAL_ID: "Y6199914",
      MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER: "9,52E+22",
    },
    {
      TERMINAL_ID: "Y61521194",
      MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER: "9,52E+22",
    },
  ],
];
```

Here is the table displaying the data

```
 <table
              class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth content-table"
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Data source 1</th>
                  <th colspan="3">Data source 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Data Source</th>
                  <th>File name</th>
                  <th>Record ID</th>
                  <th>Data Source</th>
                  <th>File name</th>
                  <th>Record ID</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr
                  *ngFor="
                    let row of MatchTransactions.matchingData;
                    let i = index
                  "
                >
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.DataSourceName[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.FileNames[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row[i].SESSION_ID }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.DataSourceName[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.FileNames[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row[i].MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Right now the output looks like this :
[image: Output]

The empty columns need to be filled with the values 296 and 9,52E+22 respectivly.

Comment: Can you show what is inside your `MatchTransactions` ?

Comment: hey @wahabmemon just a couple of other fields but `MatchTransactions.matchingData` is exactly the JSON data I included in my question so everything else is irrelevant

Comment: You have two sets of arrays in your data. Is your index 1 of your first array gong to always pertain to index 1 of your second array?

Comment: I ask because your `matchingData[0][0].TERMINAL_ID` (Y615224) does not match your  `matchingData[0][1].TERMINAL_ID` (Y61521194)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to zip the array first. And loop over the zipped array.

Here an example with lodash.

ts:

```
this.zippedArray = zip(MatchTransactions.matchingData[0], MatchTransactions.matchingData[1]);
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of zippedArray">
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.DataSourceName[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.FileNames[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.SESSION_ID }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.DataSourceName[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ MatchTransactions.FileNames[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER }}</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I added ````import { zip, of } from 'rxjs';
         this.zippedArray = zip(
        this.MatchTransactions.matchingData[0],
        this.MatchTransactions.matchingData[1]
      ); ```` to my ts code but it's not working

Comment: lodash zip, not rxjs zip. `import { zip } from 'lodash';`

Comment: @Souhail you need the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip) zip function which is for objects. the [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) zip function is for observables

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I used the lodash zip function but I still get no results here is the code I used ````ngOnInit(): void {
    this._crudService.GetMatchingTransactions().subscribe((res) => {
      this.MatchTransactions = res;

      this.zippedArray = _.zip(
        this.MatchTransactions.matchingData[0],
        this.MatchTransactions.matchingData[1]
      );
    });
    console.log(this.zippedArray);
  }````

Comment: You do the console log before the subscriptions callback kicked in. Please put it inside the subscription.

Comment: Am not exactly sure what do you mean, the console log was just for testing I removed it and nothing changed...